# ¿Cómo remover un caracter en una columna específica de un dataframe usando Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Trataba de hacer un *plot* con **matplotlib** y me lanzaba el siguiente error:

> could not convert string to float: '$143158.55'

Asumo que el error era por el `$`.

¿Existe alguna manera de removerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías remplazar el string dentro del dataframe a partir de una columna específica que aquí llamaré **tu_columna**:

```
df[tu_columna] = df[tu_columna].replace({'$':''}, regex=True)
```

Esta misma línea podrías usarla en el dataframe completo si encuntras otro caracter no numérico.

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
f = float(str[1:])
```